# Facebook Video API not Uploading Video

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It authenticates and redirects to thankyou.com like it should, but no  video is ever posted on my timeline. The video is on `www.mydomain.com/video.mp4`

```
 <?php
 $app_id = "2363xxxxxxx";
 $app_secret = "e4cd5bbxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 $my_url = "http://thankyou.com";
 $video_title = "Test";
 $video_desc = "Test";

 $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

 if(empty($code)) {
 $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
 . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
 . "&scope=publish_stream";
 echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
 }

 $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
 . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
 . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
 . "&code=" . $code;
 $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

 $post_url = "https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos?"
 . "title=" . $video_title. "&description=" . $video_desc
 . "&". $access_token;

//CURL CODES START

    $ch = curl_init();
    $data = array('name' => 'file', 'file' => '@'.realpath("video.mp4"));// use realpath
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) { // CURLE_SSL_CACERT
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
                  dirname(__FILE__) . '/src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt'); // path to the certificate
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    if( $res === false ) {
        echo curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

//CURL ENDS
?>
```

Comment: What response do you get back, does the returned object ID work when you attempt to access it via the API?

Comment: http://tyhankyou.com/?code=AQAzp7R1wJrdo3KrwtrJ6LGtvgjuE2D5Zg_doYJMrtdAaodGb65febwioIBGKwLwGKuoORga1yYR_oc_WqGWOCCT3E80z5hPs8enVdEpWpndi5HbfMRAhwI59AsXQmRGlZSt58YEqNMSkLPjicaiBz0M-JhMekRITPK2xxWunsgI8-CytfmIDnAyRilT16tsIiiyQsvKYdva12begLiMI3u2#_=_